# How to solve "Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement"

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledb

The connection works fine.I am just facing problem in this portion. My design view of RECORD table is as follows:

Name                            Type                        Size

```
     RecordID                Long Integer                             4
     BatchID                 Long Integer                             4

     ProcessID               Long Integer                             4
     EmployeeID              Long Integer                             4
     Start                   Date With Time                           8

     End                     Date With Time                           8
     Status                  Yes/No                                   1
     Hour                    Long Integer
```

Here is my code:

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        DateTime a = new DateTime(cldStart.SelectedDate.Year,cldStart.SelectedDate.Month,cldStart.SelectedDate.Day,Convert.ToInt32(ddlStartHour.SelectedValue),Convert.ToInt32(ddlStartMinute.SelectedValue),00);
        DateTime b = new DateTime(cldEnd.SelectedDate.Year, cldEnd.SelectedDate.Month, cldEnd.SelectedDate.Day, Convert.ToInt32(ddlEndHour.SelectedValue), Convert.ToInt32(ddlEndMinute.SelectedValue), 00);
        TimeSpan c = b-a;

        //insert into record table
        using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(conString))
        {
            try
            {
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO RECORD (BatchID,ProcessID,EmployeeID,Start,End,Status,Hour) VALUES (@batchid,@processid,@employeeid,@start,@end,@status,@hours)";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@batchid", Convert.ToInt32(ddlBatchNo.SelectedValue));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@processid", Convert.ToInt32(ddlSubCategory.SelectedValue));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@employeeid", Convert.ToInt32(ddlEmployeeId.SelectedValue));
                   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@start",a.ToString() );
                   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@end", b.ToString());
                   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hours", c.ToString());
                   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status",chboxStatus.Checked);
                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                txtRemark.Text = "wrong";
            }
        }

    }
```

I am trying to insert into record table but it shows me

> "syntax error in InSERT into command".

Don't know what is wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`OleDbCommand` doesn't have the concept of names parameters so you must define the parameters in the same order as in your query.

```
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hours", c.ToString());
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status",chboxStatus.Checked);
```

So you should have

```
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status",chboxStatus.Checked);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hours", c.ToString());
```

But in your query the status is before hours. Also fix your reserved words like others mention it.

Answer (score 3):

Your column names are keyword like `end,hour` so you need to surround it in braces

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO RECORD (BatchID,ProcessID,EmployeeID,Start,[End],Status,[Hour]) VALUES (@batchid,@processid,@employeeid,@start,@end,@status,@hours)";
```

Comment: Thank you so much !!! I made a silly mistake of using column names as  keywords!!Now it works completely fine

Answer (score 2):

`Start,End,Status,Hour` field names are keywords. change them to `[Start],[End],[Status],[Hour]` or either change field names in Database

Answer (score 0):

You're table name is the same as the record keyword

Try wrapping it in brackets

protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

```
    DateTime a = new DateTime(cldStart.SelectedDate.Year,cldStart.SelectedDate.Month,cldStart.SelectedDate.Day,Convert.ToInt32(ddlStartHour.SelectedValue),Convert.ToInt32(ddlStartMinute.SelectedValue),00);
    DateTime b = new DateTime(cldEnd.SelectedDate.Year, cldEnd.SelectedDate.Month, cldEnd.SelectedDate.Day, Convert.ToInt32(ddlEndHour.SelectedValue), Convert.ToInt32(ddlEndMinute.SelectedValue), 00);
    TimeSpan c = b-a;

    //insert into record table
    using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(conString))
    {
        try
        {
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [RECORD] (BatchID,ProcessID,EmployeeID,Start,End,Status,Hour) VALUES (@batchid,@processid,@employeeid,@start,@end,@status,@hours)";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@batchid", Convert.ToInt32(ddlBatchNo.SelectedValue));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@processid", Convert.ToInt32(ddlSubCategory.SelectedValue));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@employeeid", Convert.ToInt32(ddlEmployeeId.SelectedValue));
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@start",a.ToString() );
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@end", b.ToString());
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hours", c.ToString());
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status",chboxStatus.Checked);
            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            txtRemark.Text = "wrong";
        }
    }

}
```